# How to combine many nested foreachs into on Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm new to `linq` querying. Is there a way to combine these nested `foreach`s into on one `linq` query.

If not, is there a better way to update in this case ?

Thank you

```
    List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
    List<int> IDsList = new List<int>();


    foreach (var id in IDsList)
    {

        foreach (var st in StudentList.Where(a => a.StudentID == id))
        {
            foreach (var cr in st.Courses)
            {
                cr.Projects.Where(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.ProjectName) == true).ToList().ForEach(c => c.ProjectName = "Dummy");

            }
        }

    }




public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public List<course> Courses { get; set; }

}

public class course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<CourseProjects> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class CourseProjects
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Your use of a Linq `ForEach` suggests you know the basics of how to do this, but are struggling to apply it without being unable to read what you've written and understand/be sure that its logic is what you're trying to attain.  That suggests you should *not* use a train of `ForEach` lambdas, because human legibility is as important in programming as execution.  If you can't read what you've written, you should assume the next person to see your code won't, either.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var project in StudentList
  .Where(a=>IDsList.Contains(a.StudentID))
  .SelectMany(b=>b.Courses)
  .SelectMany(c=>c.Projects)
  .Where(p=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ProjectName)))
{
  project.ProjectName = "Dummy";
}
```

Comment: And better make `IDsList` `HashSet<int>` instead of `List`.

Comment: Won't this crash without materializing? Since you are editing project name during enumeration.

Comment: @user6144226 No. We aren't changing the contents of the collection we are enumerating, we are changing a property of the contents we are enumerating.

Comment: @Evk Yes, using a HashSet will likely perform better in most cases, especially if either list is large.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks, It got me thinking since the property is inside of the Where clause I'm guessing it's okay since the iteration is forward only?

Comment: @user6144226 Yes.  At the time we set the value, it has already gone past the filtering `Where`.  It'll start on the next project in the next iteration.  Actually if the courses contains multiple of the same project, or multiple courses contain the same project not doing a .ToList will allow the Where clause to filter the additional ones out as it is enumerating it, since the ProjectName will have been already changed in a prior iteration (saving a string create/assignment and whatever else may be in the loop).

Answer (score 1):

You could replace every nested foreach with a selectMany.

```
  StudentList.Where(s => IDsList.Contains(s.StudentID)).SelectMany(f => f.Courses).SelectMany(p => p.Projects).Where(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.ProjectName)).ToList().
            ForEach(c => c.ProjectName = "Dummy");
```

Whether is is really a better way to update a list remains debatable.